# How can I extend TCPDF with FPDF and FPDI?

Tags: fpdf, tcpdf, fpdi

I'm trying to extend FPDF with FPDI and TCPDF.

```
require('./fpdf/fpdf.php');
require('./tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
require('./fpdi/src/autoload.php');

$pdf = new \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi();

...
$pdf->setSourceFile(...); // from FDPI
$pdf->ImageSVG(...); // from TCPDF
...
```

Which gives me

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi::ImageSVG()

I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43361919/679449) by:

```
require('./tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
require('./fpdi/src/autoload.php');

$pdf = new FPDI();

...
$pdf->setSourceFile(...); // from FDPI
$pdf->ImageSVG(...); // from TCPDF
...
```

And I get the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'FPDI' not found

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36856707/679449) by:

```
require('./tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
require('./fpdi/src/autoload.php');

$pdf = new \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi();

...
$pdf->setSourceFile(...); // from FDPI
$pdf->ImageSVG(...); // from TCPDF
...
```

And I get the error:

> Fatal error: Class 'FPDF' not found

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FPDI comes with a class that already extends TCPDF:

```
require('./tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
require('./fpdi/src/autoload.php')

$pdf = new setasign\Fpdi\Tcpdf\Fpdi();
```

This is documented [here](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v2/installation/#index-2-2).